# Evaluating $\int \sqrt{1 + \operatorname{cosec} x}\,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$\int \sqrt{1 + \operatorname{cosec} x}\,dx $$

---

Substituting $\tan x/2 = t $

$$\int \sqrt{\sin x + 1 \over \sin x}\,dx =  \sqrt{2}\int {(1 + t)\over (1+ t^2)\sqrt{t}}\, dt $$

Now substituting $u^2 = t$

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{2}\int {(1 + t)\over (1+ t^2)\sqrt{t}}\, dt &= 2\sqrt{2}\int {1 + 1/u^2 \over u^2 + 1/u^2 }\, du\\
&= 2\int {1\over (u -1/u)^2 + 2}\,d(u - 1/u)\\
&= 2\arctan\left({u\over \sqrt{2}} - {1\over \sqrt{2}u} \right) + C\\
&= 2\arctan\left(\sqrt{\tan x/2\over 2} - {1\over \sqrt{2\tan x/2 }} \right) + C.
\end{align*}

The answer seems correct as per WA but I want to express the given answer is $\arcsin(2\sin x - 1) + C$. I am unable to get this answer.

I want a better way to solve the integral to get the given answer rather than simplifying the answer I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could of course wite
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{1+\text{cosec}\,x}&=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sin x}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{1+\sin x}{\sin x}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{1-\sin^2x}{\sin x(1-\sin x)}}\\
&\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{2\cos x}{\sqrt{1-(2\sin x-1)^2}}\\
&=\frac{d}{dx}\Bigl(\arcsin(2\sin x-1)+C\Bigr)
\end{aligned}
$$
Note that I put a ? above a $=$ at one point. In the numerator, one should in general have $2|\cos x|$ and not $2\cos x$. Thus, one has to be a bit careful with the domains where this is valid.

Another primitive function is given by
$$
-2\arctan\frac{\cot x}{\sqrt{1+\text{cosec}\,x}}
$$
(this one you get by setting $u=\cot x/\sqrt{1+\text{cosec}\,x}$).

I attach a plot with the original function (blue), your result (red, I think there is a factor 2 missing), my suggestion above (green) and finally the arcsin variant (orange). Note that the arcsin version is wrong on half of the interval where one can have a primitive.

[image]

Comment: I actually simplified before the square root of cosine, then I stopped because I was getting a modulus. Yes I am missing a 2 in my answer. thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int \sqrt{1 + \operatorname{cosec} x}\,dx = \int \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{\sin{x}}}\,dx
$$
Put $\sin{x}=t$ so that, $\cos{x}\,dx=dt$ implies $dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$ ,
$$
\int \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{t}}.\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt
$$
$$
\int \sqrt{\frac{t + 1}{t}}.\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-t)(1+t)}}\,dt
$$
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{t(1-t)}}\,dt
$$
Making perfect square,
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}}\,dt
$$
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}}\,dt
$$
It is a general form so the answer is:
$$
\arcsin{\left(\frac{t-\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}}\right)}+C
$$
After putting $t=\sin{x}$ we get,
$$
\arcsin{\left(\frac{\sin{x}}{\frac{1}{2}}-1\right)}+C
$$
$$
\arcsin{(2\sin{x}-1)}+C
$$

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you very much.